# PHP application not running on Ubuntu server

Tags: server, lamp

I just set up a AWS Lightsail LAMP instance for the first time today. I've successfully connected to the server with SFTP. I transfered a phpinfo.php file to the server and it successfully loads the PHP Info screen when I search PUBLIC-IP/phpinfo.php in the browser, so I think that the PHP is running successfully on the Ubuntu server. I have my application running successfully on my computer with XAMPP, but when I try to open my index.php file in the browser when connecting to the Ubuntu server, nothing loads in the browser. This is my first time attempting to launch an application, so I'm not very educated on how everything works yet. I know this is a broad question and there could be several issues, but any info helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my opinion you upload your files to incorrect location. You write you connect using sftp, if you upload the files directly without changing the directory they will be stored in the homedirectory of the user. But your php-files must be stored in document-root of Apache Webserver. I don't know AWS Lightsail not at all, but it seems that document root is there under /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs.
But you should know, that those instancess are not the same as native ubuntu. So you can maybe find earlier an answer under https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/lightsail or in the forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=231